# What are the differences between VRRP and HSRP?

Tags: routing, backups, hsrp, fhrp, vrrp

Are there any significant differences between VRRP and HSRP?

Comment: The OP may wish to consider GLBP to load-balance the virtual router across members if the goal is to determine the best way to protect and implement a virtual gateway among the VRRP-HSRP-GLBP options.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Besides VRRP not being proprietary, there are a few minor differences between the protocols as well:

- With HSRP, each interface must have an IP address that is separate from the HSRP group address. VRRP lets you share the Master's interface IP address.
- On Cisco devices, VRRP is configured to preempt by default, whereas HSRP is not configured to preempt by default.
- On Cisco devices, HSRP sends hellos every 3 seconds and has a dead timer of 10 seconds. VRRP sends advertisements every 1 second and has a dead timer of roughly three times the advertisement interval.
- VRRP can be configured to learn the timer configuration from the Master.

Answer (score 10):

**HSRP**
1) Cisco propriteray

2) 1 Active & 1 standby router & 1 or more listening routers

3) use virtual ip add as gateway

4) hello 3 sec & holddown timer 10 sec

5) we can enable preempt manually (standby 1 preempt)

6) multicast at:224.0.0.2 (ver1), multicast at:224.0.0.102 (ver2). Both versions use udp port 1985

**VRRP**
1) open standard (ietf)

2) 1 master & 1 or more backup routers

3) real ip address can be used (highest ip address of interface)

4) 1 sec & hold-down timer 3 sec

5) By default preempt is enabled

6) multicast at:224.0.0.18 – IP 112

Answer (score 3):

HSRP is Cisco-proprietary. VRRP is not (RFC 5798). There are probably other nitty gritty technical differences, but that is the major one. And IIRC VRRP doesn't have the ability to do interface tracking, while HSRP does - might be wrong on this though.

edit: RFC 5798 gives v6 support to VRRP. The original RFC was 2338.

Comment: VRRP can do interface tracking, at least on Cisco devices, using tracking objects.

Comment: Do note that while VRRP is not proprietary, it is patent encumbered, and a few attempts at making a free version of it has been stopped by that fact.

Comment: The patent is 20 years old.  It is probably expired. https://www.google.com/patents/US5473599

Answer (score 2):

HSRP :
1) CISCO Proprietary
2) RFC 2281
3) Multicast group Ip: 
     224.0.0.2 V1
     224.0.0.102 V2
4) Port No. UDP 1985
5) PREEMPT: By default disabled
6) Virtual Mac address: 0000.0c07.acxx
     xx = HSRP group id
7) Ipv6 Support
8) Router roll: 
     1 Active
     1 Standby

VRRP:
1) IEEE STANDARD
2) RFC 3768
3) Multicast group Ip
     224.0.0.18
4) Port No. UDP 112
5) PREEMPT: By default On
6) Virtual Mac address: 0000.5e00.01xx
     xx = VRRP group id
7) Not Support to Ipv6
8) Router Role: 
    1 Active
    1 or more working as a backup router.

Answer (score 0):

- HSRP was created by Cisco in 1994 for Cisco only, but VRRP is open source.
- HSRP default hello timer is 3 sec and hold timer is 10 sec. VRRP default hello timer is 1 sec. and hold timer is 3 sec.
- Both are used to maintain redundancy

Comment: Open standard != open source

Answer (score 0):

HSRP is manufactured by cisco for cisco in 1994.it has hello timer of 3 sec and dead timer of 10 sec.the other version of HSRP is GLBP which is identical to HSRP but has ACTIVE-ACTIVE LOAD BALANCING.

VRRP is manufactured by IETF for open vendors in 1999.it has hello timer of 1 sec and dead timer of 3 sec.it allows you to assign individual virtual ip on each interface of a routers,incase  you limited ip address(outbound).

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between HSRP & VRRP is:

HSRP:
*It support IPv6.
*It uses virtual ip as a gateway.

VRRP:
*It doesn't support IPv6.
*It uses real physical IP as a gateway.

Comment: What makes you think VRRP doesn't support IPv6? I've been using VRRP on JunOS for IPv6 for years.

Comment: VRRP does support IPv6 on almost all modern NOSes. It can support a physical interface IP address as the virtual gateway address, but that is not a requirement.